# Should I flag these comments that suggest tactical voting to satisfy a reputation threshold?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, upvotes

I found these comments (I have omitted mentioning profiles or links to avoid serial downvoting)

> This should be a comment, not an answer. USER2 20 mins ago

> I cannot make comments because a reputation is missing ... sry – USER1 14 mins ago

> Looks like you can now ;) - USER2 - 13 mins ago

> Yeah pretty cool :D I dont know how it happened ^^ – USER1 2 mins ago

Looks like USER2 upvoted USER1 answer (that has 2 downvotes already) to make USER 1 reach enough rep to post comments...

**Should I flag USER2 because tactical upvoting?**

NOTE: *USER1 does not seem to know what happened, also, USER2 didn't serial upvote, I guess just they made an upvote to allow USER2 comment...*

***I don't know if this behaviour should be punished... IMHO nope*** but maybe I'm not following SO rules, this is why I'm asking

Comment: Well, you don't KNOW this was tactical voting although it certainly **seems** like it.

Comment: For just one upvote, I highly doubt that this would be reversed by the moderators.

Comment: here's my doubt... USER1 does not seem to know what happened, also, USER2 didnt serial upvoted, I guess just made an upvote... dunno if must be punished...

Comment: @paulie merely having a suspicion of voting fraud is still enough to flag for a mod.

Comment: I would flag it. Even if the second user just upvoted once it is probably about the concept that this shouldn't be done.

Comment: I leave similar comments like the first to explain my downvote, which it often asked for ("Why the downvote?"). And well, giving someone 5 rep so that he can comment is sometimes more helpful than having him ask a new question, adding an answer instead or doing other harm.

Comment: Jordi - it's commonplace .. it's ubiquitous. Forget about it. It often happens once or twice with new users - indeed it is *polite* to upvote a competent new user to give them a point or two.  You're talking like 1 point, not a pattern of "cheating".

Comment: Apart from whether upvoting as a "tactical" way to give a specific user the commenting privilege is a violation of a specific rule (which, as per Brad Larson's answer, I don't think it actual is), is there even a *moral* issue here? Presumably USER2 (assuming they're responsible for the mystery-upvote) thinks that the upvoted-answer provides *some* value, even if it's not good *as an answer*. Upvoting (1) recognizes and rewards that value and (2) solves the underlying problem, which is that USER1 knows what they *should* do (leave a comment) but lacks the privilege required to do it.

Comment: Issue rather points back to the question whether or not it is wise to not let users comment when they don't have reputation.

Comment: A few days ago, a low-rep user happily mentioned in Chat that he'd finally found a question he could answer. I located the question via his profile and told him answer was quite good, but that he should've commented first to get the OP to clarify one or two things, rather than making educated guesses. He replied that he doesn't yet have the rep to comment. He's obviously keen to contribute to SO and was only 5 points below the required rep level, so I gave him an upvote. I wouldn't have done it if his answer had been bad, though. Unfortunately, the OP _still_ hasn't responded to the comments.

Comment: Speaking as a low-rep user, I feel that we're often admonished not to worry about losing "imaginary internet points" due to downvotes, because ultimately people can vote however they want. Following that reasoning, surely it's not worth worrying about someone gaining a few possibly undeserved upvotes?

Comment: @Yumecosmos you are told not to worry about downvotes because they arent targetting YOU. They are an indication of the posts quality. In this case, it's someone who voted on the USER. Yes, that is wrong. If the upvote was on a bad post, this sends the wrong signal to whoever else comes to it later on

Comment: "I cannot make comments because a reputation is missing" - I feel that this is a complaint. When you start at SO, you cannot add a comment, you must use answers to communicate with OP.

Comment: @Patrice Er, I think Yumecosmos is referring to situations wherein people are told not to worry about downvotes that *are* targeting them.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Unless you think this is part of a larger, coordinated scheme by User1 to act as a sock puppet for User2 or vice versa, I probably wouldn't flag this.

Moderators can't see individual votes, nor can we do anything about them. There'd be little to act on here, and your flag would most likely be declined.

If the answer wasn't an answer at all, you could flag that as "not an answer" and we could deal with the real issue here. If it is an answer, but the other user mistakenly thought it was a comment, flag the comments and we can clean them up.

Beyond that, I wouldn't worry about a single out-of-place vote.

Comment: But isn't it also a bit about the concept that users shouldn't just upvote posts from other users that they get privileges unlocked?! I mean that is not how the system should work, so I think, even if it is just one vote, the user should know that he shouldn't do that.

Comment: @Rizier123 - Frankly, I often see people be more willing to upvote new users to "help them out", so this isn't just localized to something like this. Someone choosing to be more generous with votes doesn't constitute fraud, so there's nothing for a moderator to do here. We can't invalidate votes, and I'm not wasting SE employee time over a single vote. If you want to provide a comment suggesting someone not vote in that way, go ahead. You don't need a moderator for that.

Comment: I'll second Brad's opinion, and freely admit to being more generous in upvoting new (<100 rep) users.  Especially for questions, I generally +1 as long as there's been a good faith effort on the part of the asker.  (ie I don't necessarily expect them to know they need to indent their code block 4 spaces to trigger proper auto formatting; but do expect it to be correctly indented internally.)

Comment: If the answer is flagged appropriately, a mod can convert it to a comment right? There's no immediate need for the poster to gain some rep.